# PHP send email message not working

Tags: php, html

i need help for my php contact form which is wrongly coded

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="contact_form" >
<form method="post" name="contact" action="contact.php">
<label for="author" style="font-size:14px;">Your Full Name:</label> 
<input type="text" id="author" name="name" class="input_field" />
<div class="clear h20"></div>
<label for="email" style="font-size:14px;">Your Phone Number/Email:</label
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="input_field" />

<div class="clear h20"></div>
<label for="text" style="font-size:14px;">Message:</label> 
<textarea id="text" name="comment" rows="0" cols="0" class="required"></textarea>
<div class="clear h20"></div>

<input style="font-size:16px;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"  />
</form>
</div>
```

BELOW IS THE CODE THAT BEING LOADED FORM THE CONTACT.PHP TO THE HTML
PHP CODE: (contact.php)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$to = "xxx@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Us";

// data the visitor provided
$name_field = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email_field = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$comment = filter_var($_POST['comment'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//constructing the message
$body = " From: $name_field\n\n E-Mail: $email_field\n\n Message:\n\n    $comment";

// ...and away we go!
mail($to, $subject, $body);
?>
```

Comment: Are you using wamp or Xamp? if yes, is it online or offline. and where does u form post to?

Comment: plz anyone find the mistake in the code because i dnt want to rechange the entire coding...plz guys

Comment: it is online on a server

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error sending email PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591260/error-sending-email-php)

Answer (score 0):

you just can not shut down the bracket!
valid code is:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = "xxx@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Contact Us";

// data the visitor provided
    $name_field = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email_field = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $comment = filter_var($_POST['comment'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//constructing the message
    $body = " From: $name_field\n\n E-Mail: $email_field\n\n Message:\n\n    $comment";

// ...and away we go!
    mail($to, $subject, $body);
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe explaining where he is doing this would help?

Comment: i didnt understand...i am still a noob a programming and with your help, i can improve myself

Comment: @user2135539 it says:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in /contact.php on line 12

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close your { at the end of your code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$to = "xxx@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Us";

// data the visitor provided
$name_field = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email_field = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$comment = filter_var($_POST['comment'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//constructing the message
$body = " From:" .$name_field."\n\n E-Mail: ".$email_field."\n\n     Message:\n\n    ".$comment";

// ...and away we go!
mail($to, $subject, $body);
}
?>
```